# C# - WMI query of multiple servers too slow

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-server-2008, wmi

I'm trying to return all enabled features from a remote win2008 server. And that wasn't any problem at all really - as long as I knew what exactly to query.

The problems I'm having however is when my query doesn't find a result, it takes forever to validate if the feature is installed or not - sometimes up to 2 minutes. (Not good enough when querying over 600 nodes).

The following code is the fastest way I've found of doing it, however as I said: it takes forever to return false:

```
 public bool serverFeatureEnabled(string machineName, Win32_ServerFeature_ID id)
    {
        ManagementClass serviceClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_ServerFeature");
        string strScope = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", machineName);
        ConnectionOptions conOpt = new ConnectionOptions();
        serviceClass.Scope = new ManagementScope(strScope, conOpt);

        foreach (ManagementObject obj in serviceClass.GetInstances())
        {
            if ((UInt32)obj["ID"] == (uint)id)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Does anyone have a better idea of doing this, I don't mind if it not using WMI queries at all.

All I want to do is to speed it up a bit really.

I hope I made some sense!

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

I have tried to "directly select required feature from server features with ManagementObjectSearcher class" as proposed by Sergrey V.

It did speed up the return of the first false, however it takes around 14 sec to finish, that all adds upp to 140 minutes of all the servers queried in the cluster.

**Edit 2:**

I tried to run tests against Win32_ServerFeature using WBEMTEST (Windows Management Instrumentation Tester), the connection to a remote computer seems to be the problem - running the test against one of the remote computers takes about 12 seconds to connect and around 2 seconds to return the data.

So the solution proposed by Sergrey V seems to be the fastest solution for WMI queries so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run the action in series.  I don't know if WMI has a bottleneck internally but the most obvious optimisation is to run the entire thing in Parallel.

Comment: @M Afifi thanks, that's what I'm thinking too - Using Parallel.ForEach method (System.System.Threading.Tasks) on a List<string> containing all the hostnames.

Comment: @RobinNilsson you've got the gist of it :).  There are much richer parallel libraries now (Task for e.g.) depending on your dotnet version.

Comment: @M Afifi - ah look at that! PLINQ will be interesting, hopefully I will be able to connect to all the 600 nodes simultaneously so instead of waiting for 140 minutes I should get this done in the time it takes for the slowest connection to be made. I'll post back the results!

Comment: @M Afifi - Thank you for help! This was exactly what I was looking for. The use of Task.Factory.StartNew() is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Try to directly select required feature from server features with ManagementObjectSearcher class:

```
            string serverName = "serverName";
            string className = "Win32_ServerFeature";
            string propertyName = "ID";
            int propertyValue = 144;
            string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1} = {2}", className, propertyName, propertyValue);
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
            string scopePath = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", serverName);
            searcher.Scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(scopePath));
            ManagementObjectCollection mCollection = searcher.Get();

            bool featureEnabled = mCollection.Count > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you. That speeds it up quite a bit, from around 40 sec to return false - to around 14 sec. 
That's a really good improvement but still 140 min per server cluster.
If anyone have any suggestions on how to do this without using WMI I would be very happy.
(The account executing the program is a domain admin account and any ports can be opened on the remote machines really).

Answer (score 1):

So here is what I ended up doing:
 First of all as proposed by M Afifi I started a new task for each node in a list.
The WMI queries are then being executed parallel using **'Task.Factory.StartNew()'**.
(using System.Threading.Tasks;)

The full execution of all nodes in the list takes now about 12 sec!

```
 referenceList.connectionNodes().ForEach(x =>
            {
                var genericTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        regkeyFactory.testParallelExecution(x);
                    });
            });
```

Thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Faster way is to scan all in one, i've made an HWID class using ManagementClass and it takes only 0,07s to get the unique hardware id of the machine